# Error when executing gcloud command

Tags: google-app-engine

Just installed Google Cloud SDK and whenever I try to run the gcloud command, it gives me this error:

```
\Google\google_appengine was unexpected at this time.
```

I have tried googling for this error but I haven't found anything. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

I am using Windows 8.1 and just installed Google Cloud SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is an already known issue which is occurring often. This happens when it updates to Cloud SDK version 274.0.0 in Windows. You may find more information [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/146458519).

There is a workaround provided in this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489843/google-cloud-was-unexpected-when-executing-gcloud-command/59492536#59492536)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this question really had the same issue as a recent install, but the problem, or rather bug within the installer, is that you are using a directory that contains spaces within it. At some point of the script the space causes the command to be split up incorrectly, causing the error.

I had the same message and fixed it by re-installing the Google Cloud SDK in a directory without spaces (c:\Google\CloudSDK)