# "\Google\Cloud was unexpected." when executing gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The instalation of Google Cloud SDK went right.
The problem is when I try to execute a gcloud command (even if gcloud -h) I have this output:

> \Google\Cloud was unexpected.

I'm on Windows 10. Python 2.7.17 is correctly setup.

Comment: This is really strange. Have you already tried to perform another clean install ? Try and see if performing these steps helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59435745/2190639

Comment: Version 2.74 on Windows is broken. This link has your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59458323/8016720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Hanley said, my version was broken on Windows. Google has fixed the problem with the version 2.74.0.1.
Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

There is already a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/146458519) for issues when updating to Cloud SDK version 274.0.0 in Windows. Please check it. As a workaround installing Python in `C:\Python27` and then Cloud SDK in `C:\Cloud_SDK` could help.

I suggest to migrate to Python 3 as Python 2 will not be maintained past 2020.  [Here](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) is more info about it.