# Error gcloud execution, after reinstalling

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I've been using `gcloud` command for deploying my app in app engine for weeks.

But one day (today) It starts to fail.

`gcloud` command gives me

`Didn't expected \Google\Cloud at this moment.`

in my console.

I reinstalled `python` and `google sdk`, but I can't be able to execute it again.

I recheck my path environment variables.

I'm using windows.

I'm lost with this issue.

It would appreciate any kind of clue.

Comment: Which version of Cloud SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an already known issue which is occurring often. This happens when it updates to Cloud SDK version 274.0.0 in Windows. You may find more information [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/146458519).

There is a workaround provided in this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489843/google-cloud-was-unexpected-when-executing-gcloud-command/59492536#59492536)

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't see that post! Thank you!